# is $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ or $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 - 1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

According to this resource,
https://pgssblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/tp6-pgss_finalpresentation.pdf

Any real associative unital algebra is isomorphic to either the complex numbers, split-complex numbers, or the dual numbers.

If that is the case, then $\mathbb{R}^2$ (direct product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$) must be isomorphic to either split-complex or dual numbers since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is clearly not a field since it contains zero divisors.
But I am convinced after many tries that isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ to either split-complex or dual numbers do not exist, and starting to question whether there are only 3 up to isomorphism.

Edit: it clearly is not $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ since $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not have nilpotent elements, so that narrows it down a little.

Edit2: I think I got really close here, sending $(1,0)\mapsto \frac{1+x}{2}$ and $(0,1)\mapsto \frac{1-x}{2}$, then following where each basis goes, $(1,1) \mapsto 1$ which is expected, I think this solves it!

Comment: It is the first time I see the name "split-complex numbers", but even the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) states "On the basis $\{e, e^*\}$ it becomes clear that the split-complex numbers are ring-isomorphic to the direct sum $\mathbb {R} \oplus \mathbb {R}$ with addition and multiplication defined pairwise. I urge you to check this isomorphism yourself.

Comment: yea that does it, I didn't think about how the name "split"-complex really implies that it is split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the split complex numbers, $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$. An explicit isomorphism is $$(a,b)\mapsto a\frac{1+j}{2}+b\frac{1-j}{2}$$
where I write $j$ for the image of $x\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$.

A way to see this is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has two nontrivial *idempotents* - elements $e$ such that $e^2=e$ (trivial idempotents are $0$ and $1$), namely $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. One then finds two idempotents for the split complex numbers and matches them up.

**The classification**

The classification follows from two facts about a two dimensional, unital, associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

1. Every element $x$ must obey a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ not all zero (this follows from the dimension).
2. Fix an $x$. Depending on the discriminant of the quadratic, we can replace $x$ with a linear combination $y=\alpha+\beta x$ such that $y^2\in \{0,1,-1\}$.

From this, we can replace a basis $\{1,x\}$ with a basis $\{1,y\}$ such that $y^2\in \{0,1,-1\}$, giving the three possible algebras. This in turn provides another way to find the isomorphism!

Answer (score 2):

There's a relevant theorem called the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Over_univariate_polynomial_rings_and_Euclidean_domains) that can help you in a case like this one.

Since $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, and $x-1$ and $x+1$ both generate maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x]$, they are a pair of comaximal ideals.  The CRT applies so that $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-1)\cong \mathbb R[x]/(x-1)\times \mathbb R[x]/(x+1)\cong\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

That explanation itself does not constructively give you the isomorphism mentioned already, but chasing through the proof you *can* recover that same isomorphism.

Comment: I like this method! You *can* get an explicit isomorphism this way too by looking at the proof of the CRT, of course.

Comment: wow amazing how we can apply CRT here!!